# speech recording and translate

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have a problem with convert from "wav" to "flac".

Command:

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd -t wav -d 0 -q -r 16000 | flac - -s -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o daveconroy.flac
```

Always get the error message:

```
ERROR: raw format options (--endian, --sign, --channels, --bps, and --sample-rate) are not allowed for non-raw input
```

But with the following command I can record it, but playback is extremely noisy.:

```
arecord -t raw -f S16_LE -r 8000 | flac - -f --endian little --sign unsigned --channels 1 --bps 16 --sample-rate 8000 -s -c -o test.flac
```

Project link:
https://daveconroy.com/how-to/turn-raspberry-pi-translator-speech-recognition-playback-60-languages/

https://makezine.com/projects/universal-translator/

I have searched with my colleague for hours, unfortunately unsuccessful, also already tried with sox.

Maybe there is a Linux professional among you who can help me.

Comment: why aren't you asking at a linux site?

Comment: Surely there is someone in this world who has this project from daveconroy in operation or has fixed the problem. The project (see link) is made with a Raspberry Pi. Linux helper website: https://unix.stackexchange.com? Do you know any other websites?

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question, but I've never used `arecord` - all I can offer is this:

install `ffmpeg` in the "usual way":

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get update  
...
$ sudo apt-get full-upgrade 
...
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
...
```

Once installed, you should be able to convert your `.wav` file to a `.flac` file as follows:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i "Your WAV file.wav" -c:a flac "Your WAV file-converted.flac"
```

Hope that helps. FYI, SE also has a ["Sound Design" site](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/why-does-a-flac-file-have-a-lower-bit-rate-than-the-cd-file) where you may find more specific help.

Comment: How can I use this command with your suggested command?
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd -t wav -d 0 -q -r 16000 | flac - -s -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o daveconroy.flac

ffmpeg -i "Your WAV file.wav" -c:a flac "Your WAV file-converted.flac"

Comment: @chilyourlifefist: I'm not sure they can be used together. The command in my answer was intended to be used to convert an existing .wav file to a .flac file. That was my understanding of your question.